# Android: setImageResource in adapter changing image 3 positions later

Tags: android, android-adapter, swipe-gesture

I am using AndroidSwipeableCardStack to do a tinder like interface with a 5 star rating system. When I click on a button that is meant to change the image. The image changes three cards later not in the current card.

This is the project I used: https://github.com/wenchaojiang/AndroidSwipeableCardStack

I assume it is to do with it pre-loading the next card as a recyclerview normally does but I am really not sure.

This my adapter below, you can see at the bottom I call setimageresource on the one star rating image button onclicklistner. I set a Log.d and the button click is registering immediately upon click but the change in the image resource appears only after 3 cards have been swiped.

Edit: So I noticed that regardless of the project I imported, my adapter is only extending ArrayAdatper. So I guessed that the problem might be in the getView method and that I might need to override something else (not sure). But the important point, I checked the position in getView by logging the position and sure enough it said position 0,1,2,3 without anything being swiped away. This is analogous to the offset of the setImageResource so I believe they are interlinked but unfortunately that doesn't bring me any closer to an answer.

Thanks for your help.

```
public class SongPreviewCardsDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SongDatabaseMappingAdapter> {

    public SongPreviewCardsDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }
    ImageButton oneStarRating;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, final View contentView, ViewGroup parent) {

       // Initialise Song Views
       SongDatabaseMappingAdapter item = getItem(position);

       TextView songName = (TextView) (contentView.findViewById(R.id.songNameTextView));
       songName.setText(item.getSongTitle());

       com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView songImage = (CircularImageView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.songImageView);
       String ImageURL = (item.getPictureURL());

       Picasso
               .with(this.getContext())
               .load(ImageURL)
               .into(songImage);

       // Initialise  Rating Buttons
       oneStarRating = (ImageButton) contentView.findViewById(R.id.ratingButton1);

       // Create OnClickListners for Ratings Buttons
       oneStarRating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

               oneStarRating.setImageResource(R.drawable.starfull);
               Log.d("Star", "Star Clicked");

           }
       });

       return contentView;

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getView` can be called at any time on any item, so if you want something to stay set on a view, you have to model it.

I don't know if your `SongDatabaseMappingAdapter` class is something you can change or not, but I'll assume you can change it.

- Add a variable to your item class, like `boolean mOneStar`.  Getter/setter left as an exercise for the reader.
- In `getView()` make your item `final` so you can refer to it in the `onClick` callback:

  ```
      final SongDatabaseMappingAdapter item = getItem(position);
  ```
- Use the variable in `getView` to set up your view:

  ```
      oneStarRating = (ImageButton) contentView.findViewById(R.id.ratingButton1);
      oneStarRating.setImageDrawable(null); // clear out recycled value
      if (item.isOneStar()) {
          oneStarRating.setImageResource(R.drawable.starfull);
      }
  ```
- In your `OnClickListener`, set the property on the item and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

  ```
      oneStarRating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

              Log.d("Star", "Star Clicked");
              item.setOneStar(true);
              notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
      });
  ```

The main point is:  Never change a view from an event handler.  Always change the item from the event handler then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, and always change your view in `getView()` based on the item.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I understand until the last part. I created the getter/setter, I changed the getView method with the if statement. This is working perfectly. The thing that has now got me puzzled is how to do the OnClickListner. It is a  CardStack. In my createView i do the following:  mCardStack = (CardStack)view.findViewById(R.id.cardstackcontainer); and as you said I can do mCardStack.setOnClickListener(); However not sure how this makes the star change if the star itself is clicked (There will be 5 stars). Will that make the star change if anywhere on the card is clicked?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that `CardStack` was actually the list itself.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much that has been killing me. I did have to mahe two changes to get it to work (and these are probably pad practice) so please let me know if or how I need to change them. When I declared the getOneStar/setOneStar I had to actually say it was false or I got a null pointer and also where you put oneStarRating.setImageDrawable(null); I had to comment that out because again I got a nullpointer error. regardless it is working Thanks!

Comment: the `setImageDrawable(null)` was my attempt to clear out any existing drawable.  However, I looked at the `CardStack` source and it doesn't seem to recycle views anyway, so leaving this out shouldn't hurt anything.  Cheers